# C++ library for making Jax WS calls

Tags: c++, soap, jax-ws

I want to know if there are any C++ libraries which allow me to make JAX WS calls for a web service to a server. (Mainly the SOAP message part - the serialization and de-serialization of SOAP message.) My web service is in java but i need to invoke it using c++.

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 1):

Use GSOAP (http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)  it supports (most of) the full SOAP/HTTP spec and should be fairly easy to use in calling your JAX-WS service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually cannot use gSOAP. Hence I am trying to use Axis2/C now.